# Add www and remove slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to always add www to my website and remove the slash at the end but only for the homepage.

I had this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, since it was always removing the slash it lead to a bunch of problems with our images etc (because it would be pointing on http://www.example.commedia instead of http://www.example.com/media).

Anyone could point me out how to do this ?

Comment: Its not really clear what youre asking, what does your input look like, and what do you want the output to be? are you just trying to remove the very last slash?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to force-add the www at the beginning of the website and remove the slash but only for the main page. So my desired output would be http://www.example.com while the inputs would be, for example, http://example.com/ or http://www.example.com/ etc. My problem was that with my script to remove the slash, it removed it for the entire website. While the www doesn't matter much, the slash does as it allows to reach subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the apache2 [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) you obtain the desired results with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^www\." [NC]
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^$"
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"      "http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L,R,NE]
```